# How to configure Quarkus extension attribute?

Tags: quarkus

I would like to change attribute **allow-non-standard-wrappers** value in Quarkus undertow extension configuration.

In Wildfly, it's done in standalone.xml undertow subsystem. How do we do such configuration change in Quarkus ?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think this is something you can configure in Quarkus

Comment: So it's currently not able to configure extension attributes at all ? only default values are allowed ?

Comment: Here is where you can find the HTTP related properties that can be changed at runtime: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/undertow/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/undertow/runtime/HttpConfig.java#L31

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus makes a lot of choices about how things (like undertow) should work in order to optimize for build-time compilation and define things that will work well native mode.

Undertow is used for servlets, but how servlets work in quarkus is constrained. Resteasy is used for REST, and Vert.x is also used for other http traffic.

Configuration elements for http generally (where servlets are just one piece) are here: https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference